# How to display an alert using client-side JavaScript after a post has happened on the server side?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rest, client-server

Im very new to servers and node js and js but I am trying to construct a dynamic web page. On this webpage I have a comment form where people can leave a comment. My problem is that on the server-side this comment form works fine but I am trying to implement some client-side js so that when they submit a form if an error occurred (e.g. not all fields were filled) or if no error occurred an alert appears on the webpage saying an appropriate message for either case. I also want the form to clear after the submit button has been pressed and the details have been saved to the server if there was no error. Currently the form resets before the details save to the server so in the server all the fields saved are blank and I get this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/comment 404 (Not Found)
handleFormSubmit    @   main.js:43
```

this is my code :
**Index.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Comment!</h1>
            <form action='http://localhost:3000/comment' method='POST' id='CommentSection'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='username'>username</label>
                    <input class='form-control' name='username'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='Title'>Info</label>
                    <input class='form-control' name='title' >
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='Comment'>Comment</label>
                    <input class='form-control' name='comment' >
                </div>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        <script src='client.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```js
let AllComments=[];
app.post('/comment', (req, res) => {
    const com = req.body;
    console.log(com);
    AllComments.push(com);
    res.status(201);
});
```

**client.js**

```js
async function commentSubmit(event) {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8090/comment');
    alert('success');
    CommentSection.reset();
}
const CommentSection = document.getElementById("CommentSection");
commentForm.addEventListener("submit", commentSubmit);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add a `.then()` method call to your `handleFormSubmit` method, so:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/comment').then(() => {
    alert('comment added');
})
```

`fetch` returns a `Promise`, and is an `async` method call, so in your case, `alert` is triggered after the `fetch` call is made but not necessarily completed. The `.then()` method is triggered once the `Promise` is resolved, so in order to run code once this happens, you store it in the `.then()` method.

Now in your specific use case, you want to handle successful calls and errored calls. But there is one other consideration - are you only using failed calls to determine whether a call is successful, or can the server's response signify an error? By default, `fetch` doesn't convert the response to `json` (assuming your data is being returned from the server as `json`. . For this, you would need to do the following (assuming the server returns a success/fail response as well:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/comment').then((res) => {
    return res.json();
}).then((res) => {
    if (res === 'success') {
        alert('comment added');
    } else {
        alert('An error has occurred when trying to add your comment');
    }
}).catch((e) => {
    alert('An error has occurred when trying to add your comment');

})
```

A few other points that I had missed originally, but from the conversation in the comment thread:

Since your API is exposed by the server as a `POST` request, you need to add additional options to your `fetch` request, changing the method to `POST`, as well as adding the data that you want to send to the server. To do this, you can add the following:

```
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    // where data is your form fields
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}

// Replace '...' with code from above or whatever functionality you 
// need once Promise resolves
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/comment', options).then(...)
```

For more on `fetch`, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

To get form data values, if there aren't too many, you can try this for each of the fields: `let val = document.getElementById('someId').value`

Lastly, the way your form is currently set up, once you hit submit, it will refresh by default. If you want to prevent that from happening, before the `fetch` call, add `event.preventDefault()`, where `event` is the `EventListener` that was triggered (your current method signature should be sufficient for this).

Comment: thank you so much! this fixed the fact that empty strings were being stored on the server. However I'm still getting the error I was getting before?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help I've actually learnt so much about fetch just from this question !

Comment: `main.js:43 GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/comment 404 (Not Found)
handleFormSubmit @ main.js:43` This error always appears after I press the submit button eventhouh( before I added the suggested error handler) It would append to the array of comments and do whats its supposed to despite showing an error.

Comment: Do you also have anyway of checking that all the fields are filled in the form?

Comment: Ive also just realised that a couple seconds after I submit a comment I get a page which says 'This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.' even though I have not disconnected my server.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have `action` in the `form` element as well as the javascript call? They are redundant and I'm not sure if both being present could be causing some issues, so I would suggest removing all attributes aside from `id` from your `form` element.

Comment: There's also one other issue with the `fetch` call that I missed originally. By default, `fetch` uses `GET` as the request method, however your API is exposed to `POST` requests, and there's also data you need to pass to your API, I'm assuming. I'll update the answer with this corrected

Comment: do you have any idea why its returning this error now:    `main.js:60 POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/comment 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: What port is your server running on?

Comment: 3000- i define it to run on that port earlier in my server.js code which is not in the snippet of code I provided above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226497/discussion-between-sal-and-userj).